# Получить информацию о нагрузке железа

Tags: python, python-3.x

можно ли как-нибудь получить информацию о том сколько сейчас использовано оперативной памяти (не скриптом а вообще всей системой), и загруженность диска в процентах пример вывода:

```
Ram Used: 2.11 GB
Ram total: 6 GB
DISK: 10%
```

Comment: На какой системе?

Comment: А что такое "загруженность диска" ? Просто если вы не про объем, а про скорость, то в процентах это очень сложно выражать. Потому что надо разбираться какой из параметров мерять и главное, что брать за 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import psutil

ramTotal = psutil.virtual_memory()[0] / 1024000000
ramUsed = psutil.virtual_memory()[3] / 1024000000
ramUsedInPercent = psutil.virtual_memory()[2]
diskUsed = psutil.disk_usage('/')[3]

print(f'Ram total: {ramTotal} GB\nRam used: {ramUsed} GB ({ramUsedInPercent}%)\nDisk used: {diskUsed}% ')
```

**Вывод:**

> Ram total: 16.75992 GB
>
> Ram used: 6.590928 GB (39.3%)
>
> Disk used: 93.0%

**Источник: https://pypi.org/project/psutil/**